# LayoutParams change only takes effect in fullscreen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

im using Xamarin with MvvmCross.

Ive done a FragmentDialog with a recyclerView inside, the list is populated via bindings on xml file, so i have no adapter and i should keep it this way.

If im not wrong, theres no built in way to make the recyclerView take only the size needed for its content, this should not be a problem, but in this case i need the list to start from bottom...

So i did this (its a custom fullscreen dialog) :

```
        MvxRecyclerView list = Dialog.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerview);
        list.LayoutChange += List_LayoutChange;
```

Then in layoutChange

```
 private void List_LayoutChange(object sender, View.LayoutChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MvxRecyclerView list = Dialog.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerview);

        int itemHeight = list.GetChildAt(0).Height;

        if (itemHeight != 0)
        {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams prms = list.LayoutParameters;

            prms.Height = itemHeight * list.GetAdapter().ItemCount;

            list.LayoutParameters = prms;
            list.LayoutChange -= List_LayoutChange;
            list.RequestLayout();
        }
    }
```

That was working fine, the list get exactly the height needed and the list looks like it starts from bottom.

Now the client tell me that he doesnt like the fullscreen dialog and wants the status bar, i think that should be easy, just to remove this line at the dialog creation right?

```
    dialog.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

But looks like its not that easy, when the dialog its not fullscreen the layoutParams change seems to have no effect, it just dont do nothing.

My method is being called and i get the right item height, it just dont change the recyclerview height.

Notice that setting fullscreen at creation and clearing the flag after the recyclerview params change works

So looks like it only works during fullscreen mode.

Can someone throw some light at this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, RecyclerView was not aware of its size.
Since last update to the support lib, it is !

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

> The RecyclerView widget provides an advanced and flexible base for creating lists and grids as well as supporting animations. This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

I would suggest to wait for the Xamarin wrapped lib (there is already a beta https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/23.2.0-beta1)

Comment: Ive ended doing it without the recyclerView, its nice to know this for the next time, but my question was about my workaround not working without fullScreen...